# How to Display all videos in a folder

Tags: php, html, video-streaming

i am scripting the code where you know i can list all the video files of a specific folder to get listed in webpage.. but somehow i am not able to get the output of the same so request you all guys if anyone can help in this matter... below listed is the code with the output snap.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$dir = "videos/";
$videoW = 320;
$videoH = 240;

if (is_dir($dir))
{
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){

        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

            if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                echo 
                "
                    <div style='display: block'>
                        <video width=\"$videoW\" height=\"$videoH\" controls>
                          <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/mp4\">
                          <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/ogg\">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                ";

            }

        }

        closedir($dh);

      }
}
?>
```

i am using windows 10 (64 bit).. i don't know anyhow this code is not working for me.

[image: webpage output snap]

it would be really helpful if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: doesn't look like the code is being interpreted by your web server as PHP. have you configured PHP in your web server properly and restarted the web server?

Comment: how can i configure the PHP ? actuall i am new to PHP

Comment: @bansi yea, PhpStorm doesn't seem to report any syntax error.

Comment: code is ok, what version of php are you using ?

Comment: @BondT for WIN it's easiest to get something like `xampp`

Comment: @adam K i have installed xampp but then too its not working. even i have installed PHP console extension for chrome

Comment: If anyone have any idea how can i do it without using PHP, can you please share code ?

Comment: move the code to the document folder of your xampp and try `http://localhost/yourcode.php`

Comment: @bansi this the error i got while running with xampp  
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'style' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\Test.php on line 17

Comment: there is no syntax error in your php code and it works.

Comment: @bansi any how i have managed to rid off the error but now it doesn't plays video :(

Comment: did you copy the videos also in the 'videos' folder inside the xmapp document root (where your php file is)?

Comment: I tested it and the script works perfectly.

Comment: @bansi yes i did copy the videos in c:\xampp\videos then too its not playing

Comment: is your php file in `c:\xampp`? i think from your earlier post the videos should be in `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\videos`

Comment: @bansi it is in c:\xampp\phpAdmin\

i have mentioned the full path of videos in coding as 
$dir = "c:/xampp/videos/";

Comment: @bansi i have moved videos folder to C:/xampp/phpMyadmin/videos then too it is not working...

Comment: you should **NOT** mention the full path. `$dir = "videos/";` is what you need. the path in your harddrive is not available to your web server.

Comment: @bansi finally it is done... thanks a lot for the help.... :) can you help in titling the video file.. i want to name the video files same as my file name... also i want to arrange it like table row and table.. can you give me idea ??

Comment: nice to hear it worked. you can just add titles and other layout stuff to your html. btw, you need a good basic understanding on how web servers and web sites work

Comment: @bansi yeah i know... but can't get time for all that stuff... you will be shocked to hear but i know all the in and out of software but regarding web i am really really dumb.... i can work out on VB Programming, Excel Programming, Access Programming, Fox Pro but when comes to web all my weapons are useless... lol

Comment: @bansi tell me onething is their anyway that we can run this script without the help of xampp ??

Comment: you cannot run this without some sort of web server (xmapp is one easy to install web server for beginners). because the your PHP code is executed by web server and the output is sent to your browser. If you look into the source in your browser it will be totally different than your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it's working prefectly, you probably using old version of php, you need to contact you hosting provider or you do it through cpanel https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/php-configuration-plugin